# Getting $2^{-N} + 2^{-N+1} + ... + 2^0 + ... + 2^{-N}$ from $\sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|}=2^{-|-N|}+2^{-|-N+1|} + ... + 2^0 + 2^1 + ... +2^{-N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the unordered sum $\sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|}=2^{-|-N|}+2^{-|-N+1|} + ... + 2^0 + 2^1 + ... +2^{-N}$
Assuming $N$ is positive, is there any way to get  $2^{-N} + 2^{-N+1} + ... + 2^0 + ... + 2^{-N}$ from this without needing to specify, e.g. that for $2^{-|-N+1|}$ we should have $N < -1$, for $2^{-|-N+2|}$,  etc.? I ask this since, for the case $N=1$, it seems to me the notation $\sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|}=2^{-|-N|}+2^{-|-N+1|} + ... + 2^0 + 2^1 + ... +2^{-N}$ is actually false since it implies there is another term between $2^{-|-N+1|}$ and $2^0$.

It seems I would also need conditions in the case I used the notation without the middle terms, e.g. $2^{-|-N|}+2^{-|-N+1|} + ... + 2^{-N}$, since the absolute values here depend on the positivity or negativity of $|-N+x|$. In either case, would there be a way around this?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "get ... from this"? The expresisons are very different

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I forgot to say $N$ is positive, but I'm trying to algebraically get one from the other. I'm wondering if there is a way, without needing to state the above mentioned conditions ( $2^{-|-N+1|}$ requires  $N < -1$, the next term $2^{-|-N+2|}$ requires $N < -2$ etc.)

Comment: @shintuku Not sure what you mean by those "*conditions*". You wrote that $N \gt 0$, and in that case all of $-N, -N+1, \dots, -N+(N-1)=-1$ will be negative without any additional conditions. In fact the whole sum can be written as $\sum_{-N \leq i \leq N} 2^{-|i|}= 2^0 + 2 \cdot \sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} 2^{-i}$.

Comment: hm I agree the question was oddly phrased. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like $\sum\limits_{n=0}^N 2^{-n}-1=\frac{1-2^{-(N+1)}}{1-2^{-1}}-1$.